# Accessing Protected Members from a QList of Classes eg QList<Account*>

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I am trying to get the total balance of a list of accounts that are stored in a QList using the QT framework.

My issue is that the total balance needs to access the protected member balance from the class which it does not allow me to do.

This question is from an assignment for university and the question already gave me the UML of the program and there is no getter function for the member variable balance.

My question is, is there any way to access balance from the QList without using a getter function

I have tried adding a new class pointer type, i've tried accessing it directly and tried creating a new class and assigning the class in question passed to it using a assignment constructor

```
class AccountList: public QList<Account*>
{
public:
    ~AccountList();
    bool addAccount(Account* a);
    double totalBalance();
    void doInterestCalculations();
    QString toString() const;
    QStringList customersWithHighestPoints() const;

private:
    Account* findAccount() const;

};

class Account
{
public:
    Account(QString cn, QString an, double ir, QString ty);
    Account(const Account & x);
    Account& operator=(const Account& x);
    QString getCustName() const;
    QString getAccNum() const;
    QList<Transaction> getTransaction() const;
    QString toString() const;
    QString getType() const;
    double getInterestRate() const;
    virtual void transaction(double amt0) = 0;
    virtual void calcInterest() = 0;

protected:
    double balance;
    QList<Transaction> transactions;

private:
    QString custName;
    QString accNum;
    double interestRate;
    QString type;
};

double AccountList::totalBalance()
{
    double totalOfBalances = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < this->size(); i++)
    {
        totalOfBalances+= at(i)->balance;
    }
    return totalOfBalances;
}
```

My error using QT Creators IDE is "double Account::balance' is protected" within the context of "totalOfBalances+= at(i)->balance;"

Comment: What you are asking for is the intended working of the `protected` keyword of the C++ language. What is preventing you from adding a getter function OR making `AccountList` a `friend class` of `Account`?

Comment: My reason for not adding a getter was it was not specified in the given UML. That is why I am trying to find other ways around using it. incase my Lecturer finally replies to me with a "No you can't add an extra getter". Thank you for your suggestion I will implement it now for testing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand why you can't add a getter for this `protected` data member.

But if you really don't want to add it, you can do as ***@Botje*** suggested. Declare `AccountList` as `friend` of `Account`. This way, `AccountList` will be able to access the `private` and `protected` members of `Account`.

If you don't know how to do it, add `friend class AccountList;` in the declaration of `Account` (Assuming `AccountList` is already known, if not, do forward declare it).

Comment: My reason for not adding another getter is for the sole reason of it not being given in the UML supplied by the assignment question. I want to find other ways of accessing it incase the lecturer responds with "No you can't add extra getters". I will try the friend suggestion and find out if it is allowed, thank you for the assistance.

Comment: @SKYWVRD Yes, perhaps the getters are not specified in the UML because they are quite implicit, I don't know. But anyway, the `friend` method will work as expected :)

Comment: the UML specifies getters for every variable except that one, that's why I find it so strange. The friend function seems to work perfectly :) thanks